# ActiveAdmin paginate form inputs has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination, activeadmin, formtastic

I have something like this:

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :name, :actor_movie_relationships_attributes

  validates :name

  has_many :actor_movie_relationships, autosave: true
  has_many :movies, through: :actor_movie_relationships

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :actor_movie_relationships

end
```

And:

```
class ActorMovieRelationship < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :actor

  validates :movie, :actor, presence: true

end
```

Since `Actor` can have many movies, I'd like to paginate the `ActiveAdmin` form that is used to administer these relationships.

Currently I have this form (which is NOT paginated):

```
form do |f|
  tabs do
    tab 'Actor' do
      f.inputs 'Basic Information' do
        f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys
        f.input :name
        f.input :deleted
      end
    end
    tab 'Movies' do
      f.inputs 'List of movies' do
        f.has_many :actor_movie_relationships, heading: '', new_record: 'Add a Movie', allow_destroy: true  do |a|
          a.input :Movie, collection: Movie.dropdown_names_map.call
        end
      end
    end
  end

  f.actions
end
```

Any idea how to add pagination to `Movies` in this form?

Comment: Good luck with that, has_many won't help. You'll need a custom solution, maybe with jQuery datatable.

Comment: @Milan Solution with select2_multiple is better. Take a look https://github.com/mfairburn/activeadmin-select2 or https://github.com/platanus/activeadmin_addons